Group von Neumann algebra for LCH groups
Let $G$ is a locally compact Hausdorff group with Haar measure $m$. Consider the Hilbert space $L^2(G):=\{\xi:G\to \mathbb{C}: \int_G |\xi|^2 \mathrm{d}m <\infty\}$ and the left regular representation $\lambda:G \to \mathcal{B}(L^2(G)):g\mapsto \lambda_g$, where
$$
(\lambda_g\xi)(h):=\xi(g^{-1}h), ~~(\xi \in L^2(G); g, h\in G)
$$
and $\mathcal B(L^2(G))$ denotes the set of all bounded operators on $L^2(G)$.
Now consider the group von-Neumann algebra $W^*(G):= \lambda(G)^{''}\subseteq \mathcal{B}(L^2(G))$.
My question is:

When is $W^*(G)$ a factor?

I know that if $G$ is countable discrete group then $W^*(G)$ is a factor iff $G$ is ICC. But what about the general case? What about for compact groups? Is there any references (books,article etc) for this? Thanks.

What is $\mathcal B$? Is it the group of isometric linear automorphisms?

For a Hilbert space $H$, $\mathcal{B}(H)$ denotes the set of all bounded operators on $H$.

For compact groups, the answer is never (except the trivial case $G = {e}$). This is because $W^\ast(G)$ has a one-dimensional summand corresponding to the constant function $1$ in $L^2(G)$.

You probably should email an expert in type III vNa’s for the general case. I believe there is an equivalent condition similar in spirits to ICC, but I don’t know the details.

I think as in the discrete case, if you have a non-trivial conjugacy class with finite Haar measure, you get a non-trivial element in the center simply by integrating the left-regular representation over the conjugacy class. I don't know if you still get equivalence.

@MaoWao I’m not completely sure, but I think you need unimodularity for that to work, at least if one just copies the exact same argument as in the discrete case.

@DavidGao I guess you're right. I didn't try to fill in the details. One probably also needs to rule out the case of zero measure.

@MaoWao Yeah, though in the zero measure case, the case with finite conjugacy orbit actually works, because you can just sum $\lambda_g$ in the conjugacy orbit instead of doing an integral. Probably one needs some version of this using distributions to accommodate this.
